# Understanding the theorem: Closed subset of a compact space is compact.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, metric-spaces

The theorem in title can be proved as follows: 
Let $F\subset E\subset X$ and suppose that $F$ is closed relative to $X$ and $E$ is compact. It is to be noted here that since $F=F\cap E$, $F$ is closed relative to $E$. 
Let $\{F_a\}$ be an open cover of $F$, then clearly $H=\{F_a\}\cup F^c\supset E$ and since $E$ is compact, there exist a finite subcover $J$ of  $H$ so that $J\supset E\implies J\supset F$. Hence, $F$ is compact.

My question is what happens when $F$ is closed relative to $E$ but not relative to $X$? Will $F$ still be compact? 
**Attempt:**  There exists a closed subset $D\subset X$ such that $F=D\cap E\subset D$. How do I take it from here? 
Any suggestions, counterexamples? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to reference $X$ at all. Everything works if you stay inside $E$ the whole time. One of the main ideas of subspace topology is to let you do things like this: Take a subset and pretend that that is the entire space you care about.

$F$ is closed relative to $E$, and $E$ is compact. Cover $F$ with opens (relative to $E$). Note that together with $F^c$ (complement relative to $E$), this forms an open cover of $E$, so it has a finite subcover. Take this finite subcover, remove $F^c$ if it's in there, and you have a finite subcover of the original cover. Thus $F$ is compact.

Comment: Whether or not  a set is "closed" (or "open") is *relative*.  A subset of both A and B can be close relative to one but not relative to the other.  "Compactness" is NOT relative.  If a C is "compact" as a subset of set A then it is compact relative to any other set that contains it.  Notice that any topological space is both open and closed (relative to itself) but some topological spaces are compact and some are not.